# buildConfigField метод не виден в отдельном gradle файле

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle

**Дано:**

1. Несколько `flavors` (`en`, `es` etc)
2. Файл `myData.properties` для каждого `flavor` в папке `project/config/{FLAVOR_NAME}`
3. Самостоятельно созданный `gradle` файл для заполнения полей в `BuildConfig.java` из данных файла из п2

**Цель:**

Вызвать мой метод в процессе сборки конкретного выбранного `flavor` и заполнить поля в `BuildConfig.java`

**Проблема:**

Я могу передать в мой метод имя `flavor`-а в виде строки и таким образом в методе получить путь до файла с данными, но `buildConfigField` метод в этом случае не виден.

Также я могу передать `ApplicationVariant variant` в мой метод и вызывать `variant.buildConfigField` в моём методе. Но в этом случае я не могу получить переменную `ApplicationVariant variant` в `productFlavors` блоке `build.gradle(module app)`. Я могу получить её лишь за пределами этой секции путём пробега по всем вообще вариантам сборки `applicationVariants.all { variant -> fillArrays(variant)}`, но в этом случае я обязательно должен или поместить файлы с данными для всех вариантов или не кидать ошибку при отсутствии оного.

**TL/DR:**

Как вызвать `buildConfigField` метод в собственном `gradle` файле или как получить `ApplicationVariant variant` внутри блока `productFlavors`

---

**marketSkusCreator.gradle**

```
ext {
    fillArrays = { variant ->
        def pathToFileWithData = "config/" + variant.productFlavors[0].name + "/marketSkus.properties"

        if (rootProject.file(pathToFileWithData).exists()) {
            def marketSkusPropertiesFile = rootProject.file(pathToFileWithData);
            def properties = new Properties()
            properties.load(new FileInputStream(marketSkusPropertiesFile))

            //buildConfigField - method not found, so I cant pass only flavor name as string to fillArrays method
            //buildConfigField('String[]', 'OLD_SKUS', properties.get("marketSkusOld"))
            variant.buildConfigField('String[]', 'OLD_SKUS', properties.get("marketSkusOld"))
            variant.buildConfigField('String[]', 'VER_2_SKUS', properties.get("marketSkusVer2"))
            variant.buildConfigField('String[]', 'INAPP_SKUS', properties.get("marketSkusInapp"))
        } else {
            logger.lifecycle('pathToFileWithData: {}', pathToFileWithData)
            throw new GradleException("You need to have marketSkus.properties file in root of project with " +
                    "marketSkusOld," +
                    "marketSkusVer2," +
                    " variables to build project")
        }
    }
}
```

**build.gradle(module app)** (с сокращениями)

```
import com.android.build.gradle.api.ApplicationVariant

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply from: '../marketSkusCreator.gradle'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

    productFlavors {
        es {
            fillArrays(curVariant) //how to get it - {curVariant} (type: ApplicationVariant)
        }

        en {
            fillArrays(curVariant) //how to get it - {curVariant} (type: ApplicationVariant)
        }
    }

    //this works, but I do not want to call method for each flavor during each build
    //applicationVariants.all {ApplicationVariant variant ->
    //    fillArrays(variant)
    //}
}
```

---

Этот же вопрос на англо-саксонском: [buildConfigField method not found in separate gradle file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45153156/3212712)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такой файл ***marketSkusCreator.gradle*** для вас должен подойти:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher
import java.util.regex.Pattern

def getCurrentBuildType() {

    Gradle gradle = getGradle()
    String  tskReqStr = gradle.getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString()

    if (tskReqStr.contains("Release")) {
        println "getCurrentBuildType release"
        return "release"
    }
    else if (tskReqStr.contains("Debug")) {
        println "getCurrentBuildType debug"
        return "debug"
    }
    return "";
}

def getCurrentFlavor() {

    Gradle gradle = getGradle()
    String  tskReqStr = gradle.getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString()

    Pattern pattern;

    if( tskReqStr.contains( "assemble" ) )
        pattern = Pattern.compile("assemble(\\w+)(Release|Debug)")
    else
        pattern = Pattern.compile("generate(\\w+)(Release|Debug)")

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( tskReqStr )

    if( matcher.find() )
        return matcher.group(1).toLowerCase()
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}

ext {
    fillArrays = { variant ->
        def pathToFileWithData = "config/" + variant.productFlavors[0].name + "/marketSkus.properties"
        def buildTypeName = variant.buildType.name
        def flavorName = variant.productFlavors[0].name;

        if (getCurrentFlavor() == flavorName && buildTypeName == getCurrentBuildType())
        {
            project.logger.lifecycle(pathToFileWithData)
            if (rootProject.file(pathToFileWithData).exists()) {
                def marketSkusPropertiesFile = rootProject.file(pathToFileWithData);
                def properties = new Properties()
                properties.load(new FileInputStream(marketSkusPropertiesFile))

                //buildConfigField - method not found, so I cant pass only flavor name as string to fillArrays method
                //buildConfigField('String[]', 'OLD_SKUS', properties.get("marketSkusOld"))
                variant.buildConfigField('String[]', 'OLD_SKUS', properties.get("marketSkusOld"))
                variant.buildConfigField('String[]', 'VER_2_SKUS', properties.get("marketSkusVer2"))
                variant.buildConfigField('String[]', 'INAPP_SKUS', properties.get("marketSkusInapp"))
            } else {
                logger.lifecycle('pathToFileWithData: {}', pathToFileWithData)
                throw new GradleException("You need to have marketSkus.properties file in root of project with " +
                        "marketSkusOld," +
                        "marketSkusVer2," +
                        " variables to build project")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

А уже в ***build.gradle(module app)*** вызываете:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            fillArrays(variant)
        }
```

P.S. функция `getCurrentFlavor()` взята [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34679933/5805982)

Comment: Спасибо! Это то, что нужно! =)